# How does the recent Chinese quantum supremacy claim compare with Google's?

Tags: high-performance-computing, quantum-computing

Very recently, China [claims](https://www.livescience.com/china-quantum-supremacy.html) achieving 'Quantum Supremacy' with the world's fastest Quantum Computer. Their computer was designed as a circuit of lasers, beam splitters and mirrors (see [figure bellow](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/early/2020/12/02/science.abe8770)) and to solve a very specific problem called Gaussian boson sampling.

[image]

The quantum computer from Google, for example, consists of microscopic circuits of superconducting metal that entangle 53 qubits in a complex superposition state. In the case of IBM, their quantum chips are formed by [microwave resonators in combination with Josephson superconducting junctions](https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/developers/). In case of the IBM, there is already, an open source SDK called [Qiskit](https://www.ibm.com/quantum-computing/developers/) that expresses quantum computing concepts intuitively and concisely in Python. In both cases, it is possible to program the computers to solve different tasks.

My questions is: **how honest is the Chinese claim of quantum supremacy?**

Answer (score 34):

> "how honest is the Chinese claim of quantum supremacy?"

It's equally (or at least as) honest in comparison to Google's claim.

In a comment to [this answer at Quantum Computing Stack Exchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11895/why-google-has-used-sqrtx-and-sqrty-instead-of-x-and-y-in-supremac/11955#comment15587_11955), Craig Gidney (who works at Google and was a co-author on Google's Quantum Supremacy paper), confirmed that the classical computer would have been `2^(20*7/4) = 34359738368` times faster if Google's hardware used CZ gates instead of their gates. This would mean that the 10,000 years that they said it would take classical computers to do the calculation that Google did, would become 9 seconds.

Furthermore IBM pointed out that the estimations Google made about the time it would take the classical computer, assumed that the classical computer could only use RAM and no disk at all, and if you allow the classical computer to use disk (which in this case, since they used Oak Ridge National Lab's Summit supercomputer, has petabytes available rather than just terabytes) then even though I/O is slower on disk than RAM you will save so much time by not re-calculating things, that you will get several orders of magnitude further speed-up for the classical computer.

I'm not aware of anything like this for the Chinese experiment, but to be clear: [boson sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson_sampling) is not enough to do "universal" computation, however universal computation is *not* a requirement for quantum supremacy. The probability distribution from which boson-samplers sample, is [#P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP)-difficult to calculate on a classical computer, which means that no polynomially scaling classical algorithm is known to be able to simulate such a distribution. [Discussions have taken place](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2244/2293) on the Quantum Computing Stack Exchange about whether or not boson sampling can be used to "calculate" the permanent of a complex-valued matrix (this is known to be a #P problem for classical computers), for example.

Furthermore, Figure 1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.01450) shows that it wasn't hard for the authors to simulate 144 qubits on a classical computer. That paper was published 1 year earlier than Google's quantum "supremacy" claim! This was discussed in more detail [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/30167/2293).

In any case, "quantum supremacy" is a buzzword and until people are actually using quantum devices to solve useful problems, classical computers are superior because people actually find them valuable enough to purchase.

Comment: Re: "buzzword", I think that's why it's being dropped in favor of _quantum advantage_.

Comment: @stafusa The [reason the phrase is being discouraged](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-03781-0) is much more because of the historical context of the word "supremacy" being associated with racism. My paragraph about it being buzzword would remain the same if it was called "quantum advantage" because truly there is zero computational advantage of using a quantum computer right now, for any real-world computation. I don't deny though, the benefits of pursuing quantum technologies, since if we can improve them, they may truly have advantages over classical technology.

Comment: In reference to the claim that "no one knows how to program anything with [the gate that was used]": Section VII-F of the [supplement to the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.11333) explains how to decompose arbitrary two qubit interactions into the gates that were used and this conversion is available in Cirq via the `cirq.google.ConvertToSycamoreGates()` optimizer. I certainly won't say it's a *convenient* gate set, but people have used it.

Comment: @CraigGidney That comment is very much appreciated, and I will incorporate it into the next edit of my answer, thanks so much! The decomposition of CZ into fSim gates seems even more complicated than I ever imagined. It seems if I really wanted to solve a small version of a real-world problem on Sycamore with gates I know (like CZ), there would be an overhead due to these extra gates that are needed, which will slow down Sycamore's speed, not by 2^35 but the classical computer also won't be simulating CZ either (it would be solving the problem directly). Real supremacy needs lots more qubits!

Comment: @NikeDattani There is actually a more direct decomposition of arbitrary 2 qubit interactions that doesn't go through the CZ gate, which uses at most 4 Syc gates (instead of the 6 you'd need using the CZ decomposition as an intermediary). I think this is what is done in cirq, though it is not explained in the paper. For comparison, decomposing into CZs you'd need at most 3 operations to do arbitrary interactions.

Comment: @CraigGidney I had to look up the SYC gate which seems to have been defined for the first time in one of your papers from earlier in 2020. I appreciate that a quantum algorithm for solving a real-world problem can be written in terms of Sycamore's gates. More gates would be needed than in the supremacy experiment, and therefore there would be more decoherence, and I'm not sure if the effect of that on the final performance has been rigorously estimated? I suppose noise can creep up, accumulate, and get "compounded" in ways that cancel or even outweigh the theoretically exponential benefits :)

Comment: Related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/30167/2293

Comment: Re: "Boson sampling allows us to **solve #P problems** for which no polynomially scaling classical algorithms are yet known" - this is slightly incorrect. Although the distribution of samples from BosonSampling experiments is given by the permanent, which is #P-complete, we aren't able to actively solve #P-complete problems with a BosonSampler, as that requires running the sampler an exponential number of times.  Perhaps something like "Boson sampling is related to #P-complete problems for which no polynomially scaling classical algorithms are yet known"...?

Comment: Also regarding the comment "there would be an overhead due to these extra gates that are needed, which will slow down Sycamore's speed" - who cares about a linear decrease in speed because you've increased your gate count linearly, when you have an exponential speed-up because you're using a quantum computer anyways? The bigger problem with inefficient compiling/transpiling between Sycamore gates and CZ or CX gates, which I know you know, is the loss of fidelity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MarkS, and nice to see you here. Welcome to this community! Have you seen [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2244/2293) which was asked in the very early days of QCSE? I'll edit my answer here and you can let me know what you think of the edited version.

Comment: @MarkS Thanks for your second comment, I didn't see it when I started to write my response to the first comment. Suddenly [I got a badge for getting my 1000th visitor on the QCSE question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=2293)! That visitor must have been you, unless my visits to my own question count, or unless someone clicked on the link in my last comment within just a time span of ~8 minutes :) As for your comment, I agree that the number of CZ gates would be a linear multiple of the number of Google's gates, but I'm not sure about speed.

Comment: Hi @NikeDattani - thanks for your welcoming comments. I'll be honest, I don't know much - or anything - about matter modeling, as I had thought that DFT stands for Discrete Fourier Transform :) But I am interested in learning. And yes, I had seen that early QCSE as I'm a +1 for the question and the two answers. TBH I don't think the answers are perfect and I'm not you can measure the Permanent even up to additive error with BosonSampling - additionally Scattershot BosonSampling doesn't start off with the first $m$ modes occupied so the comment about the first column I think is incomplete...

Comment: But, given gIS and DaftWullie's vast contributions to QCSE I'm not in any position to add more to what they've already answered! And I like your edit to this answer.